# How to use the new tools to do development on my ancient Fez Hydra

Tags: hardware, software

I dug out my ancient mainboard [Fez Hydra](https://www.seeedstudio.com/FEZ-Hydra-Mainboard-p-1106.html) and am trying to use to do my hobby project.

Upon reading the [instruction](https://docs.ghielectronics.com/software/netmf/getting-started.html), I found that it requires to install VS 2013.

I have VS 2019 installed already and I do not want to poison my shiny new PC with the old VS.

So just wondering may I use VS 2019 to do the development?
If not, what is the best approach to do the job without polluting my system?

Comment: i read the instruction page you linked ... there is no word `require` on that page

Comment: read the 1st line on that page, you will see  ```Download and install Microsoft's Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition.``` @jsotola

Comment: it does not say that it a requirement ... maybe it is an old post